# angular material date-range-picker bug that should not exist angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need range picker in my app.
I found angular material [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) and followed the instructions to the letter. The code is from the angular material docs. What am i missing? this error shouldnt exist. I am using many other materials just fine.

in my app.module.ts i have import of datepicker, and added module and component which uses it:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from  '@angular/forms';
.
.
.
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';  //the import i need
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingUnauthorizedComponent,
    HeaderHorizontalComponent,
    SearchComponentMini //component which uses range picker
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,  //datepicker module
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

export class AppModule { }

in component ( SearchComponentMini.ts : )

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector : 'app-search-mini',
  templateUrl: './search.component.mini.html',
  styleUrls : ['./search.component.mini.css']
})
export class SearchComponentMini   {
constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder, private searchService : SearchService){}
range = new FormGroup({
  start: new FormControl(),
  end: new FormControl()
});
}
```

in html template :

```
<mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
  <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
  <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

no matter how much i tried resetting my IDE or tinkering around i cannot get rid of this error when i run ng serve:

```
ERROR in src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-date-range-input' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-date-range-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-date-range-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    1 <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.ts:8:16
        8   templateUrl: './search.component.mini.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component SearchComponentMini.
    src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.html:1:23 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'rangePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-date-range-input'.
    1. If 'mat-date-range-input' is an Angular component and it has 'rangePicker' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-date-range-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
    
    1 <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.ts:8:16
        8   templateUrl: './search.component.mini.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component SearchComponentMini.
    src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.html:5:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-date-range-picker' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-date-range-picker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-date-range-picker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    5 <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/search/mini/search.component.mini.ts:8:16
        8   templateUrl: './search.component.mini.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component SearchComponentMini.
```

My package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.12",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.12",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.1.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.2.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "yt-player": "^3.4.3",
    "yt-player-angular": "^4.0.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.12",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your package.json

Comment: @Nitika I have added package.json file. Angular material is imported. Thank you for your reply